# Firebase Authentication failing on android emulators due to missing Play Store

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication, android-emulator

I've been tryin to get Firebase Authentication working, but I keep getting the following errors in Logcat when I try to login.

These seems to indicate that the Play Store needs to be installed for Authentication to work? Is there a way to do that on an emulator?

I'm using the "API 30 x86 with Google APIs" system image to test with and am getting this error every time.

Testing with a physical device seems to work as expected. But I've been unable to find a work-around for the emulators thus far.

### Logcat

```
2022-03-08 09:38:37.265 3784-3784/<package-name> W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: <package-name> requires the Google Play Store, but it is missing.
2022-03-08 09:38:37.270 3784-3810/<package-name> W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: <package-name> requires the Google Play Store, but it is missing.
2022-03-08 09:38:37.270 3784-3810/<package-name> W/GoogleApiManager: The service for com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zbo is not available: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_INVALID, resolution=null, message=null}
2022-03-08 09:38:37.363 3784-3784/<package-name> E/LoginActivity: sign-in failed
    com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Exception serialization error, forced wrapping. Original: com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Play Services update cancelled, original cause: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 9: Error connecting to Google Play services
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.KickoffActivity$2.onFailure(KickoffActivity.java:77)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzk.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

### LoginActivity

```java
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = LoginActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button loginButton;
    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> signInLauncher;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        // Register a callback for when the sign in process is complete
        signInLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(
                new FirebaseAuthUIActivityResultContract(),
                (result) -> onSignInResult(result)
            );

        // Register click listener
        loginButton = findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener((view) -> {

            // Choose authentication providers
            List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = new ArrayList<>();
            providers.add(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build());
            providers.add(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build());

            // Create sign-in intent
            Intent signInIntent =
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                    .build();

            // Launch sign-in activity
            signInLauncher.launch(signInIntent);
        });
    }

    private void onSignInResult(FirebaseAuthUIAuthenticationResult result) {
        if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "sign-in successful: " + user.getUid());
        } else {
            IdpResponse response = result.getIdpResponse();
            if (response != null) {
                FirebaseUiException error = response.getError();
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "sign-in failed", error);
            } else {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "sign-in failed: no response");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Documentation

This code is based on [Easily add sign-in to your Android app with FirebaseUI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Contrary to what I expected, it seems that the Play Store images are only available for some devices.**

[image: Mix of virtual devices, with and without the play store in AVD manager]

I typically use the "Nexus S" phone and "Nexus 7" tablet for testing, as they have low resolutions and are less resource-intensive. However Google does not seem to support installing the Play Store on either of those images.

To create an emulator with the Play Store pre-installed:

1. Open the Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager in Android Studio.
2. Click on "Create Virtual Device..."
   [image: Create Virtual Device button in AVD Manager]
3. Select one of the small number **Pixel Phones** that support the **Play Store.**
   [image: Supported Pixel Phones]
4. Now you will be able to download and use the images with **(Play Store)** for testing.
   [image: Download Play Store Images]
5. Happy hunting!