# FirebaseUI not working on tablet device emulator

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use FirebaseUI to authenticate users via email in my Android app. However, I keep getting an error when I try to get to the sign in screen on my tablet emulator. Strangely enough, the authentication works perfectly fine on my phone device, both emulator and physical device.

Can someone please help me identify what might be causing this error?

This is the error message when using the tablet emulator:

> E/AuthenticationActivity: Sign-in error: com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Exception serialization error, forced wrapping. Original: com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Play Services update cancelled, original cause: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 9: Error connecting to Google Play services

My dependencies:

```
implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.3"))
implementation("com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.2")
```

and also:

```
classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15")
```

My code:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI
import com.firebase.ui.auth.ErrorCodes
import com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseAuthUIActivityResultContract
import com.firebase.ui.auth.data.model.FirebaseAuthUIAuthenticationResult
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
import timber.log.Timber

@AndroidEntryPoint
class AuthenticationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val viewModel: AuthenticationViewModel by viewModels()

    private val signInLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        FirebaseAuthUIActivityResultContract()
    ) { res ->
        this.onSignInResult(res)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        viewModel.apply {
            ldSnackbarMessage.observe(this@AuthenticationActivity) {
                showSnackbarMessage(it)
            }
        }

        createSignInIntent()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        viewModel.apply {
            ldSnackbarMessage.removeObservers(this@AuthenticationActivity)
        }
    }

    private fun createSignInIntent() {
        // [START auth_fui_create_intent]
        // Choose authentication providers
        val providers = arrayListOf(
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build()
        )

        // Create and launch sign-in intent
        val signInIntent = AuthUI.getInstance()
            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setAvailableProviders(providers)
            .setIsSmartLockEnabled(!BuildConfig.DEBUG /* credentials */, true /* hints */)
            .setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
            .build()

        signInLauncher.launch(signInIntent)
        // [END auth_fui_create_intent]
    }

    // [START auth_fui_result]
    private fun onSignInResult(result: FirebaseAuthUIAuthenticationResult) {
        val response = result.idpResponse
        if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Successfully signed in
            val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
            viewModel.setUser(user) {
                finish()
            }
        } else {
            // Sign in failed
            if (response == null) {
                // User pressed back button
                showSnackbarMessage("Sign in canceled")
                finishAffinity()
            }

            if (response?.error?.errorCode == ErrorCodes.NO_NETWORK) {
                showSnackbarMessage("No internet connection!")
                finishAffinity()
            }

            showSnackbarMessage("Unknown error!")
            Timber.e("Sign-in error: ${response?.error}" )
        }
    }
    // [END auth_fui_result]

    private fun showSnackbarMessage(message: String) {
        if (message.isNotEmpty()) {
            val rootView = findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content)
            Snackbar.make(
                rootView,
                message,
                Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
    }
}
```

My tablet emulator:
[tablet device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLWMX.png)

I have checked all necessary dependencies and cleaned and rebuilt my project but the issue persists.

What I was expecting is this on my phone emulator:
[phone device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lb9AX.png)

Both devices are using Android 11

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword). It's a working solution. It's true that it doesn't use Firebase-UI, but you have full control over the authentication process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After conducting some research, I discovered that the issue I was experiencing is not specific to tablets. According to a [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71397810/firebase-authentication-failing-on-android-emulators-due-to-missing-play-store) I found, FirebaseUI is only compatible with Play Store image emulators.
[Virtual Device Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnzvV.png)